# PostgreSQL Select rows based on combination of array values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, twitter

I would like to select all rows from my database where one row contains at least two terms from a set of words/array.

As an example:
I have the following array:

```
'{"test", "god", "safe", "name", "hello", "pray", "stay", "word", "peopl", "rain", "lord", "make", "life", "hope", "whatever", "makes", "strong", "stop", "give", "television"}'
```

and I got a tweet dataset stored in the database. So i would like to know which tweets (column name: **tweet.content) contain at** **least *two* of the words.**

**My current code** looks like this (but of course it only selects one word...):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tweet_selection AS 
SELECT tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.username, tweet.geometry,
FROM tweet
WHERE tweet.topic_indicator > 0.15::double precision
AND string_to_array(lower(tweet.content)) = ANY(SELECT '{"test", "god", "safe", "name", "hello", "pray", "stay", "word", "peopl", "rain", "lord", "make", "life", "hope", "whatever", "makes", "strong", "stop", "give", "television"}'::text[])
```

so the last line needs to be adjustested somehow, but i have no idea how - maybe with a inner join?!

I have the words also stored with a unique id in a different table.

A friend of mine recommended  getting a count for each row, but i have no writing access for adding an additional column in the original tables.

**Background:**

I am storing my tweets in a postgres database and I applied a LDA (Latent dirichlet allocation) on the dataset. Now i got the generated topics and the words associated with each topic (20 topics and 25 words).

Comment: @mu is too short

id =  _integer_

Comment: @mu is too short

standard public schema of the database...

**structure of tweet**
id =  _integer_
userid = _bigint_
username = _text_
tweetcontent_raw = _text_ 
tweetcontent = _text (stemmed tweets)
tweetdate = _timestamp with time zone_

the_geom = _geometry_

the table where the words are stored (results_lda):
oid
topic_id = _integer_
word = _text_
topic_probability = _double precision_

Comment: sry my session got interrupted

Comment: and the content of tweetcontent (that's the column I am interested in) looks something like this: _first   learn   how      make   yourself   happy_ ... just as an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT ON (tweet.id) tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.username, tweet.geometry
from tweet
where
    tweet.topic_indicator > 0.15::double precision
    and (
        select count(distinct word)
        from
            unnest(
                array['test', 'god', 'safe', 'name', 'hello', 'pray', 'stay', 'word', 'peopl', 'rain', 'lord', 'make', 'life', 'hope', 'whatever', 'makes', 'strong', 'stop', 'give', 'television']::text[]
            ) s(word)
            inner join
            regexp_split_to_table(lower(tweet.content), ' ') v (word) using (word)
    ) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem :) I added 
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (tweet.id) tweet.id, tweet.content ....` 

otherwise there were duplicate entries... Great thanks :)