# How to select row based on data in array postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select a row from a postgresql table based on the data in the array of that row.
Here are the two tables:

Table 1: users

| users | --- |
| --- | --- |
| username | text |
| password | text |

Table 2: Chats

| chats | --- |
| --- | --- |
| room_id | serial |
| users | text[] |
| messages | json[] |

Let's say I have a user who's username is "Hello_world1" and I wanted to get all of the chats for that user. I would say "SELECT * FROM chats WHERE users contains "Hello_world2" I've tried "SELECT * FROM chats WHERE users[1] = "Hello_world2", but this will not work in the long because it means I would have to create another chat which is the same as this one but with that other user's name in users[1].

Comment: possible duplicate of: [PostgreSQL Select rows based on combination of array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357179/postgresql-select-rows-based-on-combination-of-array-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM chats WHERE "Hello_world1" = ANY (users)
```

Translation:

Grab every row from chats if any of the users from the users array = "Hello_world1"